# Applying filter before exporting to Excel from MySQL

Tags: mysql, filter

I want to export to Excel from MySQL DB. How can I filter the data before I export it to excel?

Before exporting I need to give some inputs to filter the data from DB that should be exported. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: please be more specific, your question is way too broad

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, open your table (assuming you just want data from this table) and use Search to indicate on what you want to filter. When you have the desired results on-screen, use the "Query results operations" panel to click on Export, then choose the CSV for MS Excel format.

Comment: I need to export using web application not using phpMYAdmin.

Comment: please help me in achieving using the web application

Comment: You wrote "from phpMyAdmin". I'll edit your question to reflect the reality.